# Access query counter per group

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to add a sort per group (Sort/Group) field in an Access Query to have sort by value as per below table:
[image]

**Note:** ID is unique index (Auto Number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a real RDBMS, one would typically use the window function [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-row_number/) for this.

```
select *
, row_number() over (partition by Group1 order by Value, ID) as Rownum
from yourtable
```

But an alternative is to use a correlated subquery.

```
select *, 
(select count(*) from yourtable t2 
 where t2.Group1 = t.Group1
   and (t2.Value < t.Value
        or (t2.Value = t.Value and t2.ID <= t.ID)) ) as Rownum
from yourtable t
```

**Extra:**

Simple tests to show the difference between `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` and `DENSE_RANK`

> ```
> create table yourtable (
>  ID int identity(1,1) primary key, 
>  Group1 int, 
>  Value int
> );
>
> insert into yourtable (Group1, Value) values
>   (10,100),(10,150),(10,150),(10,150),(10,360)
> , (200,360),(200,420),(200,420),(200,500),(200,500)
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- ROW_NUMBER (to get a sequence per group) 
> --
> select *
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Group1 ORDER BY Value, ID) as Rownum
> from yourtable
> order by Group1, Rownum
> ```

> ```
> ID | Group1 | Value | Rownum
> -: | -----: | ----: | -----:
>  1 |     10 |   100 |      1
>  2 |     10 |   150 |      2
>  3 |     10 |   150 |      3
>  4 |     10 |   150 |      4
>  5 |     10 |   360 |      5
>  6 |    200 |   360 |      1
>  7 |    200 |   420 |      2
>  8 |    200 |   420 |      3
>  9 |    200 |   500 |      4
> 10 |    200 |   500 |      5
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Emulating ROW_NUMBER via a correlated sub-query
> --
> select *, 
> (select count(*) from yourtable t2 
>  where t2.Group1 = t.Group1
>    and (t2.Value < t.Value 
>         or (t2.Value = t.Value 
>             and t2.ID <= t.ID))
> ) as Rownum
> from yourtable t
> order by Group1, Rownum
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Group1 | Value | Rownum
> -: | -----: | ----: | -----:
>  1 |     10 |   100 |      1
>  2 |     10 |   150 |      2
>  3 |     10 |   150 |      3
>  4 |     10 |   150 |      4
>  5 |     10 |   360 |      5
>  6 |    200 |   360 |      1
>  7 |    200 |   420 |      2
>  8 |    200 |   420 |      3
>  9 |    200 |   500 |      4
> 10 |    200 |   500 |      5
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- RANK (same values get same rank, but with gaps)
> --
> select *
> , RANK() over (partition by Group1 order by Value) as Ranknum
> from yourtable
> order by Group1, Ranknum
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Group1 | Value | Ranknum
> -: | -----: | ----: | ------:
>  1 |     10 |   100 |       1
>  2 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  3 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  4 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  5 |     10 |   360 |       5
>  6 |    200 |   360 |       1
>  7 |    200 |   420 |       2
>  8 |    200 |   420 |       2
>  9 |    200 |   500 |       4
> 10 |    200 |   500 |       4
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Emulating RANK via a correlated sub-query
> --
> select *, 
> (select count(t2.value)+1 from yourtable t2 
>  where t2.Group1 = t.Group1
>    and t2.Value < t.Value) as Ranknum
> from yourtable t
> order by Group1, Ranknum
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Group1 | Value | Ranknum
> -: | -----: | ----: | ------:
>  1 |     10 |   100 |       1
>  2 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  3 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  4 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  5 |     10 |   360 |       5
>  6 |    200 |   360 |       1
>  7 |    200 |   420 |       2
>  8 |    200 |   420 |       2
>  9 |    200 |   500 |       4
> 10 |    200 |   500 |       4
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- DENSE_RANK (same values get same rank, without gaps)
> --
> select *
> , DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Group1 order by Value) as Ranknum
> from yourtable
> order by Group1, Ranknum
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Group1 | Value | Ranknum
> -: | -----: | ----: | ------:
>  1 |     10 |   100 |       1
>  2 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  3 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  4 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  5 |     10 |   360 |       3
>  6 |    200 |   360 |       1
>  7 |    200 |   420 |       2
>  8 |    200 |   420 |       2
>  9 |    200 |   500 |       3
> 10 |    200 |   500 |       3
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Emulating DENSE_RANK via a correlated sub-query
> --
> select *, 
> (select count(distinct t2.Value) from yourtable t2 
>  where t2.Group1 = t.Group1
>    and t2.Value <= t.Value
> ) as Ranknum
> from yourtable t
> order by Group1, Ranknum
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Group1 | Value | Ranknum
> -: | -----: | ----: | ------:
>  1 |     10 |   100 |       1
>  2 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  3 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  4 |     10 |   150 |       2
>  5 |     10 |   360 |       3
>  6 |    200 |   360 |       1
>  7 |    200 |   420 |       2
>  8 |    200 |   420 |       2
>  9 |    200 |   500 |       3
> 10 |    200 |   500 |       3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b10f1755d9bc15a366e163d420a18206)*

Comment: The alternative solution is working but only if the values are unique. otherwise, the repeated value started count from the next No. of the previous group.

Comment: Should be fixed now. Had to surround the OR with `()`

Comment: Now it is OK except order by Rownum, not possible to sort by it.

Comment: Thanks. Well, to sort on it, could always wrap it in a subquery, then order on it outside the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
SELECT Data.ID, Data.Group1, Data.Value, 
DCount("*","Data","Group1='" & [Group1] & "' AND Value<" & [Value])+1 AS GrpSeq
FROM Data
ORDER BY Data.Value;
```

Or

```
SELECT Data.ID, Data.Group1, Data.Value, (
       SELECT Count(*) AS Cnt FROM Data AS Dupe 
       WHERE Dupe.Value<Data.Value AND Dupe.Group1=Data.Group1)+1 AS GrpSeq
FROM Data
ORDER BY Data.Value;
```

Comment: The second way is working perfectly but the first gives error on Grpseq.

Comment: Worked for me. Both have same output. Possibly the second one performs faster with large dataset.

Comment: OK now, both are working fine I found the reason of the error.