# Access Sql query renumber field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a access db with four fields, ID - Group - Section and date. Is it possible renumber the field 'Group' by an update query?
Teorically, the result should be something like pic. The grouping criterion is Section / Arrival_D

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Just define the criteria for the update.

Comment: What exactly is the rule? How many possible combinations of Section/Arrival? Review http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html

Comment: @Gustav there are N combinations of Section / Arrival. There are about 1500 records to reorder, and all of them follow the criterion I have showed in pic. I could get a similar result artificially, using a grid, grouping by fields and generating a loop, but I think there must be a solution using a query update

Comment: Your criterion is not clear to me. You need to explain why these pairs are assigned the group numbers shown. Wy are the Section2 records not in sequential groups? Are these dates MM/DD or DD/MM? Why is there no year shown? Data should be posted as text table, not image. Edit question to provide more details.

Comment: When I created the DB, I had only entered one ID field, but that identifies a single record. So I added a db field which is the Group number so as to identify all the records concerning a section and its relative arrival date which is expressed in DD / mm. This will allow me to group Section 4 - 01/06 with the second Section 4 - 01/06 which will have their own record ID but which will also have a group identifier. I'm sorry and I apologize for not being clear, but what I wanted to show in the photo with the related colors was just that.

Comment: Did you review the Allen Browne article? Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70052620/access-query-counter-per-group.

Comment: It's just the same case, I will try using similar criteria. Thanks