# Create a counter in an Access Query based on unique values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am struggling to create a counter in an access query.  I have looked through this question

[Access query counter per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70052620/access-query-counter-per-group)

but I can't make it work for me.

Here is my problem:

I have four tables in a relational database with the following MWE data

[Exam_year]

```
-----------------------------------------
|      year_id      |     year_date     |
-----------------------------------------
|                 1 |              2020 |
-----------------------------------------
|                 2 |              2021 |
-----------------------------------------
```

[Paper]

```
-----------------------------------------
|     paper_id      |    paper_name     |
-----------------------------------------
|                 1 | H556-01           |
-----------------------------------------
|                 2 | H556-02           |
-----------------------------------------
```

[Question]

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    question_id    |  question_number  |     paper_id      |      year_id      |    is_selected    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 1 |                 1 |                 1 |                 1 |               Yes |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 2 |                 1 |                 1 |                 2 |                No |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 3 |                 2 |                 1 |                 1 |               Yes |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[Question_image]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| question_image_id |           image_filename            |    question_id    |    image_page     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 2 | 2020-H556-01-01-0.png               |                 1 |                 0 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 3 | 2020-H556-01-01-1.png               |                 1 |                 1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 4 | 2021-H556-01-01-0.png               |                 2 |                 0 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 5 | 2021-H556-01-01-1.png               |                 2 |                 1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 6 | 2021-H556-01-01-2.png               |                 2 |                 2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 7 | 2020-H556-01-02-0.png               |                 3 |                 0 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 8 | 2020-H556-01-02-1.png               |                 3 |                 1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The tables have the following relationships

[image: relationships]

I have a query:

```
SELECT Question.question_id, Question.question_number, Paper.paper_name, Exam_Year.year_date, Question_image.image_filename, Question_image.image_page, Question.is_selected
FROM Exam_Year INNER JOIN ((Paper INNER JOIN Question ON Paper.paper_id = Question.paper_id) INNER JOIN Question_image ON Question.question_id = Question_image.question_id) ON Exam_Year.year_id = Question.year_id
WHERE (((Question.is_selected)=True));
```

which generates the following:

[image]

I would like to add another column at the end that is a counter beginning at 1 which increments by one when the question_id value changes.

I think I have to use dcount, but I am not sure how to implement it.

I have tried adding a column as (as per the link above)

```
DCount("question_id","Question","[Question.question_id] <= " & [Question.question_id]) AS QuestionNumber
```

this generates the following
[image]

which is assigning the row of the [Questions] table that corresponds to the question_id field (ie question_id 3 is on row 3 of the [Questions] table)

I want the last column to contain the numbers 1 for question 1 (the first unique instance of this question_id) and 2 for question 3 (the second unique instance of this question_id).

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks
Martyn

Comment: Reposting same question does not help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77802677/ms-access-query-adding-a-counter-column-for-unique-combinations-fields-in-a-rec.

Comment: question_id does not provide anything different than question_number offers. If you want all 6's to show 1 and all 12's to show 2, etc, then need dataset with only 1 record with 6 and 1 record with 12, build query on that and JOIN it to other data - otherwise VBA may be needed or migrate to SQLServer which has innate functions for this. Either provide samples of your tables as formatted text or post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Hello, sorry I thought I had changed the question by adding what I had tried but it had still failed.

Comment: question_number is not unique in the table (there are many question 2 and 3 from different papers.  question_id is a unique identifier.  I will edit my question this evening to provide sample tables.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You show that DCount attempt in comment for your other post. Could have edited that question and maybe it would have been reopened (doubtful). You are free to delete your own questions if you want.

Comment: I have now updated my question with sample data and more explanation of the problem.  Hopefully it now makes more sense and explains the issue more clearly.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your query and you can use my *RowNumber* function found [here](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers) in a simple query:

```sql
SELECT 
    *, RowNumber(CStr([question_id])) AS QuestionNumber
FROM
    YourSavedQuery
WHERE 
    (RowNumber("","",True)=0);
```

The function:

```vb
' Builds consecutive row numbers in a select, append, or create query
' with the option of a initial automatic reset.
' Optionally, a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query having an ID with an index):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber(CStr([ID])) <> RowNumber("","",True));
'
' Usage (typical select query having an ID without an index):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber("","",True)=0);
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID]), CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber(CStr([ID])) <> RowNumber("","",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowNumber(vbNullString, True)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO TempTable ( [RowID] )
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO TempTable ( [RowID] )
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber("","",True)=0);
'
' 2020-05-29. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RowNumber( _
    ByVal Key As String, _
    Optional ByVal GroupKey As String, _
    Optional ByVal Reset As Boolean) _
    As Long
    
    ' Uncommon character string to assemble GroupKey and Key as a compound key.
    Const KeySeparator      As String = "¤§¤"
    ' Expected error codes to accept.
    Const CannotAddKey      As Long = 457
    Const CannotRemoveKey   As Long = 5
  
    Static Keys             As New Collection
    Static GroupKeys        As New Collection

    Dim Count               As Long
    Dim CompoundKey         As String
    
    On Error GoTo Err_RowNumber
    
    If Reset = True Then
        ' Erase the collection of keys and group key counts.
        Set Keys = Nothing
        Set GroupKeys = Nothing
    Else
        ' Create a compound key to uniquely identify GroupKey and its Key.
        ' Note: If GroupKey is not used, only one element will be added.
        CompoundKey = GroupKey & KeySeparator & Key
        Count = Keys(CompoundKey)
        
        If Count = 0 Then
            ' This record has not been enumerated.
            '
            ' Will either fail if the group key is new, leaving Count as zero,
            ' or retrieve the count of already enumerated records with this group key.
            Count = GroupKeys(GroupKey) + 1
            If Count > 0 Then
                ' The group key has been recorded.
                ' Remove it to allow it to be recreated holding the new count.
                GroupKeys.Remove (GroupKey)
            Else
                ' This record is the first having this group key.
                ' Thus, the count is 1.
                Count = 1
            End If
            ' (Re)create the group key item with the value of the count of keys.
            GroupKeys.Add Count, GroupKey
        End If

        ' Add the key and its enumeration.
        ' This will be:
        '   Using no group key: Relative to the full recordset.
        '   Using a group key:  Relative to the group key.
        ' Will fail if the key already has been created.
        Keys.Add Count, CompoundKey
    End If
    
    ' Return the key value as this is the row counter.
    RowNumber = Count
  
Exit_RowNumber:
    Exit Function
    
Err_RowNumber:
    Select Case Err
        Case CannotAddKey
            ' Key is present, thus cannot be added again.
            Resume Next
        Case CannotRemoveKey
            ' GroupKey is not present, thus cannot be removed.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            ' Some other error. Ignore.
            Resume Exit_RowNumber
    End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide sample data, etc. so here is an example query that would generate the dense-ranking numbers in MsAccess:

```
SELECT aa.question_id
, (SELECT  Count(*)
   FROM (SELECT distinct question_id from tblYr)  AS a 
        inner join 
        (SELECT distinct question_id from tblYr)  AS b
        on a.question_id>=b.question_id
   GROUP BY a.question_id
   having a.question_id=aa.question_id
 ) as DRNK
FROM tblYr aa;
```

If your table is tblYr.

See if you can adapt.

Comment: I will add sample data later to my question when i get home from work

Comment: Just save your query into an ms access query and treat it as the tblyr in my example

Comment: I have now added some sample data to make my question clearer.  I have tried to run the above idea with my query (Query1) using the following: SELECT aa.question_id
, (SELECT  Count(*)
   FROM (SELECT distinct question_id from Query1)  AS a 
        inner join 
        (SELECT distinct question_id from Query1)  AS b
        on a.question_id>=b.question_id
   GROUP BY a.question_id
   having a.question_id=aa.question_id
 ) as DRNK
FROM Query1 aa; but it says invalid argument to function